# Contain UIViewController in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, react-native, uiviewcontroller

When developing React Native native UI components, `RCTViewManager` expects you to define a `view` method which returns a `UIView`. Here's a basic example of what I have setup at the moment, this just renders a small grey square on the screen:

```
@implementation RNThingComponent

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];

    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
}

@end


@implementation RNThingtManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
    RNThingtComponent * view;

    view = [[RNThingtComponent alloc] init];

    return view;
}

@end
```

I have built quite a few native components like this, however I'm now working on a component which expects me to setup a `UIViewController` in order to render it's views.

Is it possible to wrap this `UIViewController` in a `UIView` so that I can return the view to React Native or will I have to somehow get the `UIViewController` to work with it?

Comment: I don't think you want a view to wrap a UIViewController.  The view controller wraps a view.  I don't know react native, but couldn't you, instead of allocating a view, allocate a vc and return vc.view?

Comment: It's got to be a UIView - I've found some info on how it's done: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5807#issuecomment-181871469

Comment: Any working solution for rendering UIViewController in ReactNative ?